# How can I edit packages or remove them from an ArchLinux live image file?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, iso-image

I'm new to the Linux world.

I want to edit the live boot image in order to remove some packages. How do I edit the packages that are in a live ISO?

There's a package list within the Arch folder in the ISO file, would removing packages in this file work or do i need to do something else?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's read-only media, so you cannot alter it directly. You would need to install it onto some writable media such as a usb drive.

Answer (score 1):

The live image is built by *installing* all those packages into a temporary location, then generating the large SquashFS image from it. The only way to remove a package, then, is either to:

- a) unpack the ISO, unpack the SquashFS, modify it, repack it (mksquashfs and mkisofs);
- or b) use the official Arch tools to build yourself a *new* image.

The latter is recommended; once you get the tooling working once, you'll be able to easily build fresh images whenever things get updated. The official Arch images are built using [Archiso](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Archiso) and it already has support for custom profiles.

That being said, however, a bootable USB stick does not necessarily have to be a *live image* – it could just as well be a completely normal, writable system that happens to be installed to a USB stick. So your option c) would be to do a normal Arch installation and choose whatever packages you want (and then tweak it a little to reduce disk writes, like making sure log files aren't stored).